# Google maps loading just one record from MYSQL

Tags: php, javascript, maps

This is my first post here, o let me say hi :)

I have a problem with my google map. What I try to do is to get locations from mySQL database,  and set a marker for every location on the map. Seems prety basic and easy. But I have a very limited web-developer knowledge, being a chemist ;) What my page does - it just loads one record, not two (there are only two rows in the database anyway). You can find [the code here](http://pastebin.com/M6Jv7yK2)

I have checked the query with another script - sit gets both records, while loop also seems fine. But somehow i get just 1 marker on the map :( COuld you have a look please and check for the mistakes? I assume something is wrong with the marker generation in the loop...

Cheers, Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have one marker.

var marker_ = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: tytul,
        zIndex: id
      });

Here is a good way to handle it:
[Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Comment: But is not a new marker declared every time the loop iterates?

var marker_<?php echo $id; ?> = new google.maps.Marker

its inside the loop and a marker called marker_$id is declared, so its like: marker_1, marker_2 ? 

I am reading your link atm, I did it in a similar way before, but later I had problems with pulling the data from mySQL server :)

Thank you for help, I keep fighting on :D